# Rewriting CSS subclasses

Tags: html, css

I am using an annoying CSS stylesheet that requires all `<a>` links to be written as `<a class="nounderline">`, and various other things like that. I don't have a say in the master CSS file, but I can apply my own extra CSS to pages if I want to.

So, given the above constraint, is there a simple way to add a secondary CSS to my page such that all `<a>` tags within a specific context somehow have the above class applied to them automatically?

For example,

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>classes in CSS</title>
    <style>
      /* something like the following would be present in the master CSS: */
      .nounderline {text-decoration:none;}
      /* I want to add something like the following: */
      div.maintext a {class:nounderline;} /* I don't know... I'm guessing! */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="maintext">
    <a href="http://example.com">look, no underline!</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on this would be great!

Comment: You cannot assign classes with CSS, you'd need JS or PHP/Ruby/... - what you *can* do is styling depending on the context. But I guess you already knew that, right? :) By the way, I'd not recommend using JS. Try to be more specific with your CSS selectors, that'd solve your problem in a much cleaner way.

Comment: You might be able to avoid JavaScript if you use SASS or another CSS preprocessor. Depending on your setup, SASS's `@extend` feature could be a relatively elegant way to set this up. In the final CSS, it would be as if you had simply copied the styles from `a`, but SASS would automatically update this for you whenever you reprocessed the stylesheet so you wouldn't have to manually maintain it. See: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: The SASS option is very appealing, and the @extend feature is *exactly* what was needed, but even so I'm not sure it works in the current context.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible using CSS alone, you'd either need to use JavaScript, or edit the templates. Of course, if you know all the rules of `.nounderline`, then you can just copy them across to `.maintext a`.

**JavaScript Solution**

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".maintext a"),
    length = anchors.length, i;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    anchors[i].className += " nounderline";
}
```

If it's not *impossible* for you to manipulate the CSS, you should just do:

```
.nounderline,
.maintext a { ... }
```

I'm not a proponent of using the JavaScript solution unless you absolutely *must* - if the constraint can be lifted in any way, it really should be.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery's addClass function to all the `a` tags

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define any classes in CSS, still less “subclasses”. CSS can only refer to elements by their class that has been assigned in markup language (HTML).

If there is a style sheet that has a rule with the selector `.nounderline` and you want to apply the declarations in that rule to all `a` elements, then just copy that rule from that style sheet into your own style sheet and replace `.nounderline` by `a`.